# How do I create custom materials properties in the node editor?

Tags: shaders

Okay, so I have DONE this. Multiple times. But I can't remember wtf I did and searches for this are useless for the same reason you can't easily do research on the word "The".

What is the node that I use to create custom values to be adjusted in the materials settings? You know, so I don't have to go in through the shader editor?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the Principled BSDF?

Comment: No. I am talking about a node that you add and plug into a value and then you are able to then modify that value as a slider in the material settings sidebar.

Comment: There are any number of nodes that you can plug into a material output that provide a "slider" in the properties panel. What type of value are you trying to adjust?

Comment: I'm just going to research wherever I did this other material work.

Comment: I literally don't know how to say the same thing a third way. You designate a value to show up in the vertical stack of material items on the right hand side of the Layout workspace. I know there are existing ones. I get that. I can designate one to be among the MAIN ones.

Comment: Well, there is a "Value Node" (Add > Input > Value). That's all I can really think of.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't do it either. :( Being a blender noob is hard... so many things that I have literally done that I can't replicate...

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help. It's hard to tell what to do without knowing what value(s) you're trying to modify. When you added it before, did you add it as a node? What custom values are you adding? Like how do those values modify the material?

Comment: It's okay. This software is Hard. It's a math node. Just a single stupid value. But it really doesn't matter what or where it is in my node tree. I have a super vivid memory of adding a node, plugging it into the value I want to show up as a 'control' in the materials stack. And then naming this custom value in the side-bar tool of the node-editor. And there being a list of other custom values I had created for the material (which I now must find..).

Comment: A Group node? You can add inputs to a group in the sidebar of the Shader Editor when editing the group, and if the group node is plugged into the output the inputs you added will show up in the Properties panel.

Comment: I think you want to use a Group, which is just a way to make a custom node